SPI register addressing scheme
I have been researching SPI communication protocol to do like a GUI interface for it. However, I came across a situation where it stated that the register address of the device where it has 8-bits, only 7 out of 8 bits are taken and the MSB are altered for read/write bit. For instance, if the address is 0xF7. Write operation will be 0x77 and read operation will be 0xF7.
My question is if there are two register that has address 0x81 and 0x01, what will happened if I want to write to register 0x81? since both will results to the same control byte. Below are example of the SPI read operation:


SPI use of the initial byte (and for that matter, the rest of the bytes) is user defined. Unlike I2C, there is no SPI standard as such. Some de facto protocol definitions for specific devices (like SPI memories including EEPROM and flash) have emerged, but otherwise it’s wide open.
For the specific protocol you describe, addresses are limited to 7 bits, so the F7 and 81 cases would not be valid.
Larger SPI address spaces are possible by using additional bytes after the first control byte. Look into how SPI flash devices deal with this for a real-world example.
Thus, your GUI will need a means to deal with these protocol differences if it is to be a general tool, which could handle simple devices or more complex ones.

"SPI use of the initial byte is user defined." None of the bytes are specified by the SPI standard.

@Velvet In addition, there is even no SPI standard. But there never was a claim that the bytes are defined somehow collectively, simply that they are not.
